# Запрос данных из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, postgresql, mysql

Есть две таблицы А и Б. Они имеют связь между собой. Необходимо получить данные из обеих таблиц в одном запросе. Делеаю такой запрос

```
SELECT a.id
FROM table_a a,
     table_b b
WHERE a.id = b.table_a
  AND (a.field_1 = 'false'
  OR b.field_2 = 'true';
```

Проблема в следующем. Таблица А может содержать очень много запеисей, и только малый процент их присутствует в таблици B. Если я использую такую связь

```
WHERE a.id = b.table_a
```

То мне выберутся только те значения, которые присутствуют и в А, и в Б. Мне необходимо получить данные из соответствующие условию из таблицы А и данные по условию из таблицы Б. Если не использовать связывание, то данные будут дублироваться. Как построить запрос верным способом?

Таблица A

```
id SERIAL,
name text,
is_searchable boolean,
```

Таблица Б

```
id SERIAL
table_a reference,
is_dismissed boolean,
```

Я хочу получить все объекты из А, которые:

1. Не сохранены как отклоненные в таблице Б (у которых `is_dismissed == false`)
2. Те которые могут быть найдены (`is_searchable == true`)

В таблицу Б мы заносим объект в том случае, если мы хотим его сохранить (`is_dismissed == true`), или отбросить (`is_dismissed == false`).

Получается что запрос должен включать объекты из А "по условию" или объекты из А, которые имеют `is_dismissed == true` в таблице Б.

Проанализировав ответы понял, действительно надо использовать LEFT OUTER JOIN. Но загвоздка в том, что для разных таблиц разное условие. Те если я анализирую таблицу А то мне надо смотреть только лишь значение поля `is_searchable`, а если таблицу Б, то только значение `is_dismissed`. Следовательно, кроме UNION, вроде, нет альтернатив.

Comment: Т.е. в Б есть строки, которые не указывают на A? (Вряд ли)
Составьте таблицу

        searheable      true  false
        is_dismissed
        true              ?     ?
        false             ?     ?
        null              ?     ?

и поставьте крестики, при каких комбинациях объект попадает в результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте, что значит LEFT OUTER JOIN (или RIGHT OUTER JOIN). Правда поля из таблицы, где отсутствует соответствующая запись будут иметь значение NULL. Возможно

```
SELECT a.id
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.table_a
AND (a.field_1 = 'false'
     OR coalesce(b.field_2, 'true') = 'true');
```

(А у Вас 'true' и 'false' -- char или varchar?)

И что значит "данные из таблицы B", если написано `select a.id`?

95**Обновление.**95

Теперь непонятно с B.is_dismissed...

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.table_a
AND a.searchable
AND coalesce(b.is_dismissed, FALSE);
```

Т.е. те, у которых a.searchable и b.is_dismissed -- ложь, или соответствующая строка в B отсутствует. (Проверять -- не проверял)

Comment: Пробовал JOIN - результат один и тот же с `a.id = b.tabel_a`. Поля имеют булевый тип (значения 't' или 'f').

Comment: Так что же Вы хотите? (Желательно со описанием таблиц)

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Забыли сравнить is_dismissed с false.

    SELECT a.id, a.name 
    FROM table_a a 
      left outer join table_b b ON a.id = b.id
        AND a.searchable = true
        AND coalesce(b.is_dismissed, false) = false

Comment: Да. Но лучше просто отрицание NOT -- `AND NOT COALESCE(..`

Answer (score 1):

Напишите по запросу для каждой таблицы и объедините их с помощью union.

Comment: На первый взгляд (в консоли) решение работает. Не могли бы вы подробно раскрыть тему, почему и какие последствия использования данного подхода присутствуют?

Comment: Предложение UNION используется для объединения результатов нескольких запросов, повторения при этом исключаются.  
[Документация SQL](http://www.sql.ru/docs/sql/u_sql/ch14.shtml)

Comment: union тут не поможет. нужно не объединять запросы, а исключить один из другого, т.е. операция не объединение множеств, а вычитание.

Answer (score 1):

Задача действительно должна иметь решение как указано выше. Оператор JOIN - означает полное соединение, то есть взять все из левой таблицы и все из правой. Если использовать LEFT [OUTER] JOIN, то возьмется все из левой таблицы и то, что соответствует условию из правой. При операторе RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN тоже только наоборот. 
Синтаксис
Левая*таблица LEFT(RIGHT) [OUTER] JOIN Правая*таблица Условие_соединения

Answer (score 0):

3. UNION

Выборка из нескольких таблиц последовательно.

UNION действует как SELECT DISTINCT, т.е. отбрасывает повторяющиеся значения. чтобы этого избежать, нужно использовать оператор UNION ALL

```
(SELECT i, c FROM t1 ORDER BY i DESC)
UNION
(SELECT i, d FROM t2 ORDER BY i)
```

Answer (score -4):

По качеству вопроса: написано много букв, но так и не указано четко, какие значения имеют NULLы в этих логических столбцах.

По существу вменяемого мне вопроса могу показать следующее (синтаксические особенности мускула ВКЛЮЧЕНЫ):

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.table_a = A.id
WHERE A.is_searchable
AND (
B.id IS NULL
OR NOT B.is_dismissed
)
```

Всё это игриво намекает на COALESCE... А вопиет о неправильной схеме, где таблица-костыль `B` только мешает.